# How to have multiple of the same objects appear at once

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am writing a simple program, in this I want multiple ellipses to appear at the same time, is there a function for this to happen or a method to follow for multiple ellipses of the same kind to be produced all across the screen in different places?

Comment: I can't think of a specific function that is helpful for creating multiple ellipses but there are many examples of using p5.js functions to make multiple ellipses. For example notice how this sketch encapsulates movement behavior for multiple ellipses, https://p5js.org/examples/objects-multiple-objects.html. Look through some examples and then make an attempt to write code that does what you want, show it to us and we can help answer specific questions.

Comment: If you have code for drawing two ellipses `ellipse(); ellipse();` then both will appear at once... Have you even tried? Please read the documentation: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/ellipse